# I am facing the following error while running android xamarin apps on vs emulator for android.The screenshot is in he picture below:

Tags: xamarin.android

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7B5i.jpg)

Please help,i am stuck.

Comment: your proxy isnt working

Comment: have you tried to google the error message you are getting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224560/use-proxy-in-visual-studio-emulator-for-android